# How to manipulate client connections

Tags: opa

I'm making an on-line multiple players game using Opa，and have some questions on how to manipulate client connections.

Here is my code extract:

```
function game_view(){
    function page_ready(){
        // observe game messages
        _ = Network.observe(game_msg_received,game_channel);

        // set disconnect function
        _ = ClientEvent.set_on_disconnect_client(function(c){
            //do something when client is disconnected  
            ...
        });
    }

    <div onready={function(_){ page_ready() }}>
        //page content
        ...
    </div>
}
```

1. The disconnect function takes effect about 2 minutes (I guess it's the time of 4 ping failures) after I close my tab or window, it's too long for my case, can I adjust it and how?
2. When I leave this page (close the tab or jump to other pages), after a while some error messages will appear as follow:

[SESSION] Uncaught exception: "{OpaRPC_Server: {timeout: {client: {client: $"46rrpwmeiq28ql0d8lgz7e35zt8d701c"$; page: $934885115$}; fun_id: $"__set_game_Mygame"$}}}"
The following message is skipped.:
If you want (msg, st, ctx) debug printing set debug variable session_debug >= 200

I think it's because the page does not exist any more but function 'game_msg_received' still try to notify this page when game message is received, then how can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 3):

1 - You can't change the disconnection delay, but perhaps you can use the inactive event.

This event is raised if the client has no activity of the point of view of server (rpc calls, sends messages, ...)

Use `ClientEvent.set_on_inactive_client` to register a callback for the inactive event and `ClientEvent.set_inactivity_delay` to change the duration.

2 - Indeed it's because the page does not exists any more. You should remove your observer from the network. Use `Network.unobserve` for this.

Finally your code should look something like that

```
// set default inactive delay
// or if you change the 1st params 
// you can set for a specific client 
ClientEvent.set_inactive_delay(none, /*wanted delay*/)

function page_ready(){
    // observe game messages
    obs = Network.observe(game_msg_received,game_channel);

    // set inactive function
    _ = ClientEvent.set_on_inactive_client(function(c){
        // remove the observer
        Network.unobserve(obs);
        //do something when client is disconnected  
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it's useful. But I don't think inactive is suit for my case, cause a player may have no actions for a long time but still in the game, for example it's not his/her turn. This is similar to [Opa Poker](http://poker.mlstate.com). I don't know how Opa Poker solve it. I'm now trying to send heartbeat periodically when the page is ready, will that be too costly?

Comment: Yes it's a solution, if you use sessions to implements your heartbeat it will cost one message by heartbeat.

Comment: I think the better way to implements what you want, it's one server session, and a client timer that just send a void message to the session. But perhaps you can also use {unload} Dom.event to call a server disconnection function? It should be triggered if the client properly close the browsers (no crash, hard kill, etc..)